# is oxd server required for asp .net when connecting to gluu server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gluu

I'm new to using Gluu Server and I'm trying to make a connection using ASP .NET MVC.  Is the only way to connect to the Gluu Server through the oxd server or can I use Identity Model?

Answer (score 0):

oxd is middleware which helps RP/client effectively communicate with Gluu Server. However it's perfectly fine to call Gluu Server directly (e.g. following OAuth 2 or Connect specs). At the end it's REST based server.

You may want to check official Gluu docs:
https://gluu.org/docs/

If there is more specific question/issue, Gluu Support is great place to get help:
https://support.gluu.org